# scrollable html panel with scroll buttons using css and flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollable

I'm having layout difficulties when creating a scrollable panel using css and flexbox.  I saw this one (http://jsfiddle.net/5A9c9/)

that works well as long as no elements are added into the divs.  When I modify that and add one line (line 11 in http://jsfiddle.net/5A9c9/7/), the layout is completely messed up.  It could be almost any other tag and it still gets messed up.

```
`<!-- adding this line messes it up -->
<p>abcd</p>`
```

How do I get this to lay itself out properly?

p.s. or any other full working examples of such a panel using only css and flexbox?

Edit:
One of the issues I hit with the scrollable area using flexbox was that the elements were getting crushed and force-fitted into the area, and therefore it had no chance to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this page http://fantasai.inkedblade.net/style/discuss/flexbox-min-size/ which gave me a hint on why the components were getting crushed or started overlapping within my supposed scrollable area.  To solve it, I put a min-width size to the elements/components within my scroll area.  This allows the scroll to happen.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, use "display:flex" in your CSS if you want to use the flexbox magic. 
Set display to flex in both the outer and inner divs like so:

```
    #scrollBox {
        display:flex;        /* <---  here */
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -ms-overflow-x: auto;
        -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #scrollBox > div {
        display: flex;       /* <---  and here */
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Secondly, in your html, put your "abcd" paragraph inside the fieldset. I can't imagine you would want it outside of the fieldset... Like this:

```
        <div class="firstPanel">
            <fieldset class="firstPanel">
                <legend>Panel 1</legend>
                    <p>abcd</p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

I hope this helps some :-)